# PHP's json_encode and jQuery

Tags: php, json

I'm making an AJAX call to a page `/person/steve`:

```
$.ajax({
  url:      '/person/steve',
  method:   'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  success:  function(response){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
  }
});
```

`/person/steve` consists of this code:

```
$person = array(
  'name'    => 'Steve',
  'twitter' => '@stevelindstrom'
);

echo json_encode(array('data' => $person));
die;
```

Now, in my php, when I log the result of that `json_encode` using the PEAR Log class, I get:

```
{"data":{"name":"Steve","twitter":"@stevelindstrom"}}
```

Which is what I would expect, but if I look at the response in the Chrome dev tools, it shows:

```
[{"data":{"name":"Steve","twitter":"@stevelindstrom"}}]
```

Any idea why my object is getting stuck into an array?  I have other pages that are nearly identical (just different data), and they show up as I would expect them to...

**EDIT:**  I tried using JSON_FORCE_OBJECT and I'm getting the same result.

Comment: Is it different if you don't stringify before dumping to console?

Comment: telling jquery that the data type is json causes it to decode the json string into a native structure for your automatically. You then RE-ENCODE that structure to a json string in your console.log call. So it's the json library doing the extra array. what does `console.log(response)` show?

Comment: Ignore that line of javascript - I'm looking at the `HTTP response in the Chrome dev tools`, which I believe is before it ever reaches javascript.  However, for the curious, `console.log` shows the same thing as the HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to `json_encode` as second argument [`JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)
And do You return JSON or a string, I mean the `Content-type` header, is it `text/html` or (which should be in this case) `application/json` ?
Or maybe just JSON.stringify method wraps it into an array, try using dragonfly or other tool to see source of the server's raw response.

Comment: It already generates objects for associative arrays. There's no other way to encode them.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, the response is a json string. Which would make the JSON.Stringify call redundant. Remove that and see what happens.

Comment: Correct you are, but I'm looking in the Chrome dev tools, which is the actual HTTP response, before it ever sees javascript.

Comment: When I try your code, I get `{"data":{"name":"Steve","twitter":"@stevelindstrom"}}` so I can't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: Populates an object fine with JSON.parse of the responseText too.